# Tracing environment variable modification in the fish shell

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, fish

There's one item I used to use in `$PATH`, which is `~/.workspace/bin`. I can't figure out where it's coming from.

I changed the user shell to `/bin/sh`, logged in from TTY, checked `$PATH`, and it was clear of this item.

Then I changed the shell to `/usr/bin/fish`, I echoed `$PATH` as a first thing in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`, and that item was there!

Where could it come from?  What else is the `fish` shell doing on startup? (I have an empty `~/.profile` file)

Comment: Could be a universal variable: do `set -U` and see what variables are there. You might want to look for `fish_user_paths` -- fwiw this is why I don't use universal variables: I like configuration.

Comment: For what files fish reads when you start a shell: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#initialization

Comment: This may help: `grep PATH /etc -rI` or eventually `grep PATH / -rI`